# PowerApps - Network error when using Patch function: The specified column is read-only

Tags: patch, powerapps

The app uses SharePoint as the backend and there are no read-only system columns on the form.

The app hadn't thrown this error before, but now throws it regularly. The only change to the code was we used to use the O365 Users connector, but removed it and just use logic checks against User().Email.

I added `Notify(Concat(Errors('DataSource'), Column & " : " & Message));` as seen in the multiple similar questions and was able to see the problematic columns, but it appears to be all of them (the notify ran out of room).

One thing to note as well is I (site owner) can't recreate this error, nor can other users with full control to the site. And as one of the other similarly asked questions noted, this is sporadic, sometimes a hard browser refresh fixes the issue. Could it be a permission issue?